# Selecting all record of a table and few record from another

Tags: sql

I want to do this:

List the orders with **customer details**, but include all customers **even if they have not placed an order**

I wrote the following

```
SELECT Customers.CompanyName,Customers.City,Customers.Country,Orders.OrderDate, Orders.RequiredDate
FROM Customers 
INNER JOIN Orders
        ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID 
ORDER BY Customers.CompanyName;
```

But it returns only those who place the order. I also want to get those who does not place an order.

The database is **northwind**

Comment: You need a `left outer join` instead of an `inner join`.

Comment: Or just a `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use LEFT JOIN and see the example at [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) of it. It will fetch all record which have common `CustomerID` and also those which are not common from 1st table

```
 select Customers.CompanyName,Customers.City,Customers.Country,Orders.OrderDate, Orders.RequiredDate
    FROM Customers LEFT JOIN
      Orders
      ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
      order by Customers.CompanyName;
```